# How can I constantly check if a JSON file is updated in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm making a clock using Tkinter and Python.

What I want to achieve is having the clock run and automatically check if the JSON file (which contains the clock's visual settings) has been updated. If the JSON file has been updated, then the clock will update live.

However, this isn't the case. What I have to do is update the JSON file, close the clock program, then re-open the clock program. Only in this case will the changed JSON settings take place.

**clock.py**

```
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime
from settings import *

# Updates the program and clock settings
def tick():
    time_string = datetime.now().strftime(time_format)
    date_string = datetime.now().strftime(date_format)

    root.config(bg=background_color)

    container.configure(bg=background_color)

    current_time.configure(text=time_string,
                           font=(time_font, time_size, time_weight, time_slant),
                           fg=time_color,
                           bg=background_color)

    current_date.configure(text=date_string,
                           font=(date_font, date_size, date_weight, date_slant),
                           fg=date_color,
                           bg=background_color)

    current_time.after(1, tick)


# TKInterface
root = Tk()
root.title(window_title)

# Binds 'Esc' key to exit program
root.bind('<Escape>', exit)

# Runs program in full-screen
if full_screen:
    root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    root.config(cursor='none')

# Creates container to hold time and date
container = Frame(root)
current_time = Label(container)
current_date = Label(container)

container.pack(expand=True)
current_time.pack()
current_date.pack()

tick()
root.mainloop()
```

**settings.py**

```
import os
import json

with open('settings.json') as json_settings:
    settings = json.load(json_settings)

    # Window
    full_screen = settings['window']['full_screen']
    window_title = settings['window']['window_title']

    # Background
    background_color = settings['background']['color']

    # Time
    time_font = settings['time']['font']
    time_size = settings['time']['size']
    time_weight = settings['time']['weight'] 
    time_slant = settings['time']['slant']
    time_color = settings['time']['color']    
    time_format = settings['time']['format']

    # Date
    date_font = settings['date']['font']
    date_size = settings['date']['size']
    date_weight = settings['date']['weight']
    date_slant = settings['date']['slant']
    date_color = settings['date']['color']
    date_format = settings['date']['format']
```

**settings.json**

```
{
    "window": {
      "full_screen": false,
      "window_title" : "chronoberry"
    },
    "background": {
      "color": "black"
    },
    "time": {
      "font": "arial",
      "size": 70,
      "weight": "bold",
      "slant": "roman",
      "color": "white",
      "format": "%-I:%M:%S %p"
    },
    "date": {
      "font": "arial",
      "size": 20,
      "weight": "normal",
      "slant": "roman",
      "color": "white",
      "format": "%A, %B %-d %Y"
    }
  }
```

**Desired Effect:**

If I change the background color in my JSON file and save it, my clock should be able to update its color during run-time.

Before changing the background color

[image]

After changing the background color

[image]

**What I've Tried:**

- Re-importing the settings.py module using importlib.reload(), but the settings.py module isn't a valid argument.
- Opening settings.json, reading from it, closing it, then opening it again. However, once a file is closed, it's impossible to open it again.

Comment: _once a file is closed, it's impossible to open it again_ No it isn't.  Why do you say that?  Are you getting an error when you try?

Comment: Are you aware that `after(1, ...)` runs after 1 millisecond, not one second? Since your clock only has one second resolution, you're making the CPU do a lot more work than is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `settings` module is essentially a module of constants, which makes it quite hard to reuse. While you could do something hacky to force the `reload` like:

```
def tick():
    import settings, importlib
    importlib.reload(settings)
    from settings import *
    # ... rest of tick code ...
```

that's going to be both inefficient and a terrible misuse of the import mechanism (now instead of reading one file, you're reading two, the module and the JSON it depends on).

Instead, I'd recommend making `settings`s a little more reusable with a function that can read the data and cache it, rather than a bunch of globals:

```
import os
import json

class Settings:
    SETTINGS_FILE = 'settings.json'

    def __init__(self):
        self._load_settings()

    def update_settings(self):
        if self._last_update != os.stat(self.SETTINGS_FILE).st_mtime:
            self._load_settings()
            return True
        return False

    def _load_settings(self):
        with open(self.SETTINGS_FILE) as json_settings:
            settings = json.load(json_settings)
            self._last_update = os.fstat(json_settings.fileno()).st_mtime

            # Window
            self.full_screen = settings['window']['full_screen']
            self.window_title = settings['window']['window_title']

            # Background
            self.background_color = settings['background']['color']

            # Time
            self.time_font = settings['time']['font']
            self.time_size = settings['time']['size']
            self.time_weight = settings['time']['weight'] 
            self.time_slant = settings['time']['slant']
            self.time_color = settings['time']['color']    
            self.time_format = settings['time']['format']

            # Date
            self.date_font = settings['date']['font']
            self.date_size = settings['date']['size']
            self.date_weight = settings['date']['weight']
            self.date_slant = settings['date']['slant']
            self.date_color = settings['date']['color']
            self.date_format = settings['date']['format']
```

Now your `clock` module can import `settings`, construct a `Settings` object up front, and at each `tick` call `update_settings()` on it. If `update_settings` returns `True`, it should also reapply the configuration. The code would need to qualify the various names, so instead of just saying `date_color`, you'd put:

```
mysettings = Settings()
```

at the top level, and refer to `date_color` with:

```
mysettings.date_color
```

but that's a small price to pay to improve the code.

Comment: For the record, I agree that `inotify` interfaces would be an improvement here and should be considered, but they're (IMO) too advanced for your level of skill right now.

Comment: This is an elegant approach to my problem! I appreciate the time you took to explain this to a novice programmer. Thanks!

Comment: To my basic understanding, this is what the modified settings.py file is doing: Upon creating a Settings() object, the _load_settings() method is called. Here, the last recorded time of modification of the JSON file is stored inside of _last_update.

Comment: @leecharles_: Yup. Then each time you call `update_settings`, it checks if the JSON file has been modified since it was last loaded, and if so, reloads it and returns `True` (so you know to reconfigure with the new settings), otherwise it returns `False` (so you know you can just update the time, and leave the Tk configuration unchanged).

Answer (score 1):

How serious is this code? You could just check for the file's last modified time at some interval with `os.stat(path_to_file).st_mtime` and refresh your interface if it's later than the last time you checked. Quick and dirty.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options. 1 is the option benas has suggested. Every second or so check the last modified time of the json file to see if it has changed.

Another option is to use a package such as [PyiNotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/). This package can identify events that occur on files and folders. 1 such event is the IN_MODIFY event which triggers when a file has been modified. A list of events can be found [here](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki/Events-types).

Firstly you would need to install the package using pip:

```
pip install pyinotify
```

The following is example code (almost entirely from their documentation)

```
import pyinotify

# The watch manager stores the watches and provides operations on watches
wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()
wm.add_watch('/path/to/file', mask, rec=True)

mask = pyinotify.IN_MODIFY  # watched events

class EventHandler(pyinotify.ProcessEvent):
    def process_IN_MODIFY(self, event):
        print "Modifying:", event.pathname
```

Comment: My understanding is that `pyinotify` is not supported well (no changes in years). Most folks seem to recommend [`inotify`](https://pypi.org/project/inotify/).